# does not display div content

Tags: java, html, css, thymeleaf

I wanted to make a web application, so I started with creating the look. My frontend is poor so I wanted to use ready templates such as bootstrap navbar. I use thymeleaf additionally. I copied the example navigation bar but it looks like this:

[image: bad]

instead

[image: good]

All html files is in : 
DrinkShop\src\main\resources\templates
and css for test:
DrinkShop\src\main\resources\static\css

```
h1 {
  color:  green;
}
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Drink Shop</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/5.0.6/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />

</head>

<body>
    <div th:replace="header :: header"></div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
    <div th:replace="footer :: footer"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/1.12.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</body>

</html>

footer.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/5.0.6/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
</head>

<body>
    <div th:fragment="footer">&copy; 2016 Footer</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/1.12.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</body>

</html>

pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.myapp/groupId>
        <artifactId>DrinkShop</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>



        <name>DrinkShop</name>
        <description>Spring Application</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath />
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
                <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.3</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

</project>


header.html ( i change some names but does not matter in this case )

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/5.0.6/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" th:fragment="header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DrInK sHoP</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Something<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a th:href="@{/register}">Register</a>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        My account
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Shopping cart</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My details</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit details</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/1.12.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried check on web tools but I got on bootstrap , style

Status Code: 200 OK

Comment: Does your final HTML have multiple <html>, <head> and <body> tags? There should only be one per web page.

Comment: There's only one per web page.

Answer (score 0):

May be your `Bootstrap` is not configured or configured wrong. Make sure you have some class look like:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/fontawe/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/font-awesome/5.0.6/web-fonts-with-css/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/bootstrap/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/jquery/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/popper/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/popper.js/1.12.5/dist/umd/");
    }
}
```

and in html use something look like:

```
th:href="@{/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
th:href="@{/resources/fontawe/fontawesome-all.min.css}"
th:src="@{/resources/jquery/jquery.min.js}"
th:src="@{/resources/popper/popper.min.js}"
th:src="@{/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"
```